# check if JSON response has an object

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to filter out if a JSON response has objects, and do something if it has.

My Problem is that even if it has objects, it won't trigger the break.

Here is my code:

```
from tempmail import TempMail
import time
import pyperclip

email = TempMail()

email.generate_random_email_address()

print(email.login + '@' + email.domain)

pyperclip.copy(email.login + '@' + email.domain)

while True:
    if print(email.get_list_of_emails()) is None:
        print(email.get_list_of_emails())
        time.sleep(5)
    elif ['id'] in print(email.get_list_of_emails()):
        break
```

Comment: `print()` always returns None, so `if print(email.get_list_of_emails()) is None` is always true.

Comment: It turns out that the return value of `print()` is always `None` and therefore the `if` condition is always true and the `elif` is never executed.

Comment: Oh ok but how can i change that?

Comment: You can't change that (that `print` returns `None`).

Comment: Why are you checking the result of `print()` anyway?  What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: i create a temporary email and then check for new messages. if there are no new message then i want to continue the loop and if one message comes then stop the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(email.get_list_of_emails())` return `None`. This is why you never get the `break`. Try to remove the `print`

Try to change the code to something like the below (it will give you better visibility)

```
while True:
    data = email.get_list_of_emails()
    if data is None:
        print('data is None - going to sleep..')
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print('we have data!') 
        print(data)
        if ['id'] in data:
            print('got it!')
            break
```

Comment: thank you but it seems like the problem is with the api wrapper that i use. it always spits out 'we have data!' also if there is no email in the mailbox. and if there is an email it just says the same and does not recognize the 'id'. i know now the problem is not in my code anymore but is there a way to go around that?

Comment: Upload  2 flavors of the data to the post. One with new email and the other without.

Comment: if no mail is there: `we have data!` and then `[]` and if an mail is there: `we have data!` and then `[{'id': 257785954, 'from': 'test@ismyemailworking.com', 'subject': 'IsMyEmailWorking.com - Test ID [e9f6cf9c-d53d-4b3e-8b56-d57b2d15327b]', 'date': '2021-09-11 22:43:14'}]`

Comment: So just check that "len(data) > 0"

Comment: @critiqalfish I am glad I managed to help. You can accept the answer.